# $||a||\leq \sup_{||b||\leq 1} ||ab||$ in a C*-algebra

Tags: c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

I would like to prove that, if $a$ is an element in a C*-algebra then
$$\|a\|\leq \sup_{\|b\|\leq 1} \|ab\|$$

It is obvious if the algebra is unital. What if it is not?

Comment: Can you use $b =\frac{a}{||a||}$ (Um.... might be not good enough...)

Comment: The product $a \cdot b=0$ for all $a,b$ yields a (non-unital) Banach algebra. What happens to your desired estimate in this case?

Comment: @PhoemueX: true. I am actually in the context of C* algebras but I thought the result was more general - I'll edit the post accordingly.

Comment: Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/title-and-latex).

Comment: @Martin: noted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a $C^\ast$ algebra, this is easy. You have $\Vert a \Vert = \Vert a^\ast \Vert$ and (by definition of a $C^\ast$ algebra) you have

$$
\Vert a^\ast \Vert^2 = \Vert (a^\ast)^\ast a^\ast \Vert = \Vert a \cdot a^\ast\Vert,
$$

so that taking $b = \frac{a^\ast}{\Vert a\Vert}$ yields your claim, since the estimate $\Vert ab \Vert \leq \Vert a \Vert \Vert b \Vert \leq \Vert a \Vert$ for all $\Vert b \Vert \leq 1$ is trivial.